# Protractor throwing unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, protractor

I'm trying to get a protactor test running. But when making use of module it throws the below. I'm quite new to ES6 how to configure it.

> export { getFreePort };
>   ^^^^^^
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
>       at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)
>       at Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
>       at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Dev\Code\JG.Crowdfunding.Website\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:156:7)
>       at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (C:\Dev\Code\JG.Crowdfunding.Website\protractor.conf.js:4:18)

My babelrc file has

```
{ "presets": ["es2015"] }
```

The imported file where the error occurs looks like

```
var freeport = require('freeport');

var getFreePort = function () {
return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
    freeport((err, port) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR: Something went wrong while trying to find a free port.');
            reject(err);
        }
        fulfill(port);
    });
});
};

export { getFreePort };
```

And inside my protractor.conf onPrepare function I have.

```
  onPrepare: function () {
return portHelper.getFreePort().then(port => {
  fakeApiServer.startFakeApiServer(port);
}).then(() => {
  return browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
})}
```

and I'm doing the following further up in the protractor.conf

```
require('babel-core/register');
var portHelper = require('./test/e2e/helpers/portHelper');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out my error was that babel-register ignores the node_modules folder. In order to solve my problem I needed to do

```
require('babel-core/register')({ ignore: false });
```

Instead of just

```
require('babel-core/register');
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line, you need `port` in parentheses: `return portHelper.getFreePort().then(port => {`